# [yocs_waypoints_navi]make fail due to missing "yocs_msgs/JoystickConfig.h"

Tags: catkin-make, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am newbie for the ROS.
I am trying to install the package of http://wiki.ros.org/yocs_waypoints_navi, but met the below make issue, I already follow the suggestion from [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/280660/unable-to-catkin_make-due-to-missing-yocs_msgsjoystickconfigh/)
to run:

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-yocs-velocity-smoother
```

The installation works fine, and the build already passed, but afdterwards get below issue and compilation terminated:

```
/catkin_ws/src/yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/src/joyop.cpp:15:38: fatal error: yocs_msgs/JoystickConfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/CMakeFiles/joyop.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/CMakeFiles/joyop.dir/src/joyop.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/CMakeFiles/joyop.dir/src/joyop.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:8887: recipe for target 'yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/CMakeFiles/joyop.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [yujin_ocs/yocs_joyop/CMakeFiles/joyop.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j12 -l12" failed
```

I already installed the  ros-kinetic-yocs-msgs package.

```
~/catkin_ws$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-yocs-msgs 
[sudo] password for liangma: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ros-kinetic-yocs-msgs is already the newest version (0.6.3-0xenial-20181107-005535-0800).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Anyone can help? Thanks so much!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322590/%5Byocs_waypoints_navi%5Dmake-fail-due-to-missing-%22yocs_msgs/joystickconfig.h%22/) by [macleonsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41341/macleonsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-05-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-07**:
Can you tell us why you install `yocs_msgs` and `yocs_velocity_smoother` using `apt`, but then build `yocs_joyop` from sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry I forget detail--later I simply git clone the most update code of ros-kinetic-yocs-msgs from github and do compiling (catkin-make) then it works OK..

Thanks a lot for the feedback anyway.

---

Originally posted by [macleonsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41341/macleonsh/) with karma: 26 on 2019-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [macleonsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41341/macleonsh/) on 2019-05-15**:
@gvdhoorn
I can not find the "answered"check box on left side. Can you simply close this ticket ? thanks so much.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-15**:\

> I can not find the "answered"check box on left side. Can you simply close this ticket ?

No, I won't close the question.

Instead I've converted your comment to an answer and accepted it for you.

Note though, as explained in #q322980, you should try to avoid building packages from sources, unless you have a good reason to do it. For released packages, there is no reason to go an hunt for all source repositories and maintaining a Catkin workspace in which you build them. Just use `apt-get` to install the binary packages.